# How to generate all possibilities for triangles from 10 possible dots

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to think of the solution for this problem:

Generate all possibilities for triangle between 10 dots which are positioned like this:

```
.   .   .

.   .   . 

.   .   .

    .
```

(like a keypad on regular mobile phone)
first line : 1   2   3
second line: 4   5   6
third line : 7   8   9
forth line :     0

I am using PHP. I tried to generate using the oposite logic. (get all combinations and remove all combination that are not triangles, but that is too complicated). Is anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to ask a question about how you're trying to solve the problem rather than just looking for a complete solution.

Comment: This is probably too broad a question for Stack Overflow. If the question is narrowed a little and you can demonstrate what you've tried, it may be more acceptable on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, but probably not in its present form.

Comment: I generated all combinations of those numbers and try to manually set the array of wrong combinations and delete it from existing array, but that solution is crappy. That is why I asked here. I just need an idea, not a complete solution

Comment: And also...what is the specification?  All possible combinations of 3 dots not in a line would be a triangle...

Comment: all possible combinations of 3 dots not in a horizontal or vertical or diagonal line would be a triangle

Comment: I agree that you need to work on this a bit more, but I think the answer will be 108 triangles when you work it out correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have thought of the following:

```
$banned = array(5,8,10);
$array = array();
for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
    for($j=1;$j<11;$j++){
        for($k=1;$k<11;$k++){
            if($i != $j && $j != $k && $i != $k){
                $tmp = array($i, $j, $k);
                sort($tmp);
                if($tmp[1]-$tmp[0] !== $tmp[2]-$tmp[1] AND $tmp !== $banned){
                    $array[] = $tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));// remove duplicates
print_r($array); // printing
```

Comment: @user2331875 you're welcome, do you need an explanation ?

Comment: no I got it. great solution

Comment: Hmmm I just discovered a bug, let's pick `8,9,10`. `10 - 9 = 9 - 8` so we need to add more to the banned list and check against it ...

Comment: thanks, will look into that. this is perfect solution for now. I will debug it for sure and test it

Answer (score 2):

1. pick three points
2. test if they can form a triangle (simply test if they are in one line)
3. record it
4. repeat

Comment: this might help me. I will try it out and confirm the answer soon